# What should be Reference type of 'Password' column in idempiere to hide the characters from client?

Tags: idempiere

I am using Idempiere 3.1.
In my table i have the password column.
I set it to the string.
In window it shows the value/character to user. What should be the reference type for password ?   OR is there any other solution for it.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window -> Tab ->  Field and mark **Encrypted** flag as **true**.
If you want to make it encrypted in database, you can use **Column encryption** option from Table And Column -> Column -> Run Process button.

Answer (score -1):

> Go to Window -> Tab -> Field and mark the **Encrypted** flag as true.
>   If you want to make it encrypted in the database, you can use
>   "**Secure Content**" flag. Don't forget to sync columns.